# Ionic does not execute canActivate on route on android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

this runs as expected running `ionic serve`, but when i deploy it to andoid it just sits on my 'home' screen at launch.

edit: this works as expected on the emulator, but when debugging on a device (Galaxy S9+) it fails.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _api: ApiService, private _router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this._api.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      map(r => {
        if (r){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            const tree: UrlTree = this._router.parseUrl("login");
            return tree;
        }
      })
    );
  }
  
}
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: "settings",
        loadChildren: ()=>import("../settings/settings.module").then(m=>m.SettingsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  providers:[AuthGuard]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: have you tried connecting the remote debug tools to see if there are any errors? If so, what is the output from console.log and network tab?

Comment: make sure ur not testing on a url without https since in android sdk 28+, ur forced that the url should be https and not http, this is mostly the onlt thing that could differ in ur case since code is pure from ur side so it function the same from wherever accessed... just change from http://... to https://....